# A module cannot have multiple default exports react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, node.js, express, routes

Hej !

I have some issues in my final project with the router. When I run npm run dev

everything works in my localhost but I have some red underline in my export default bookingRouter;

I got this:

```
A module cannot have multiple default exports.ts(2528)

BookingRoutes.js(60, 16): Another export default is here.

const bookingRouter: Router

View Problem (⌥F8)

No quick fixes available
```

and

```
A module cannot have multiple default exports.ts(2528)

BookingRoutes.js(60, 16): Another export default is here.

Declaration or statement expected.ts(1128)

'try' expected.ts(1005)

Declaration or statement expected.ts(1128)

Declaration or statement expected.ts(1128)

A module cannot have multiple default exports.ts(2528)

BookingRoutes.js(40, 16): The first export default is here.

const bookingRouter: Router
```

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/F4sCo.jpg)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vIT5J.jpg)

I found some informatis that I shoude use module but stil I got redunderline

module.exports = bookingRouter;
:

```
enter image description here

Declaration or statement expected.ts(1128)

'try' expected.ts(1005)

Declaration or statement expected.ts(1128)

Declaration or statement expected.ts(1128)

View Problem (⌥F8)

No quick fixes available
```

### [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dej9Q.jpg)

Can some boy have the same issue? What is the problem? I do this like every my project in the backend and I never had this problem so I really don't understand this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without the entire code we can't see if it's a bug. Probably not.

Scroll to line 60 on `BookingRoutes.js`and remove the duplicate export.

Comment: It was problem with vsc with setting :)